# Android - Error at creating and/or starting hotword recognition

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-studio-3.0

I am using Firebase Database to store my data. When Retrieving data back using `DataSnapshot` my logcat is showing this error

```
09-06 07:55:01.782 7940-7940/? E/HotwordDetector: Error at creating and/or starting hotword recognition.
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing hotword data buffer
        at com.google.speech.micro.GoogleHotwordData.nativeNew(Native Method)
        at com.google.speech.micro.GoogleHotwordData.<init>(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.microdetection.a.a.a.b(SourceFile:14)
        at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.f.a(SourceFile:47)
        at com.google.android.libraries.assistant.hotword.f.Lh(SourceFile:33)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.voiceinteraction.hotword.a.dpg(SourceFile:34)
        at com.google.android.voiceinteraction.GsaVoiceInteractionService.dpg(SourceFile:106)
        at com.google.android.voiceinteraction.l.onServiceConnected(SourceFile:72)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1329)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1346)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:179)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5730)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:681)
09-06 07:55:01.782 7940-7940/? E/GsaVoiceInteractionSrv: Failed to perform next action.
```

This same error is repeated on each query although my app is working fine and data is retrieving correctly. Just wanted to know the reason behind this error

My code

```
 private void loadUserData(String user_uid) {
        mDatabaseReference.child(user_uid).child("User").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
               String name = dataSnapshot.child("Name").getValue().toString();
               String department = dataSnapshot.child("Dept").getValue().toString();

                etName.setText(name);
                etDept.setText(dept);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Minkoo After lot of research I came to know that this error is actually cause by My Android OS because in other devices this error doesn't shows up

Answer (score 0):

This error has nothing to do with Firebase or your code.
It depends on the operating system of your device which has implemented Google now and showing it as an error.